# Configuring inventory detail on Item Fulfillment item list, using C# and SuiteTalk

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

I am coding in C#, using the SuiteTalk Web Services to create Item Fulfillment records from existing sales orders.
I am not sure how to configure the inventory detail, when serial numbers are specified on items.

I successfully generate the item fulfillment and can update NetSuite when items are not serialized. When items are serialized, I get the following error:

> "Please configure the inventory detail in line 1 of the item list."

I run through each line item and check whether it is fulfilled, after which I add it to my new item fulfillment list as follows:

```
List<ItemFulfillmentItem> ifitems = new List<ItemFulfillmentItem>();

ItemFulfillmentItem ffItem = new ItemFulfillmentItem();
ffItem.item = ifitemlist.item[b].item;
ffItem.orderLineSpecified = true;
ffItem.orderLine = ifitemlist.item[b].orderLine;

ffItem.quantity = msg.despatchItems[i].qtyDespatched;
ffItem.quantitySpecified = true;
ifitems.Add(ffItem);

ItemFulfillmentItemList ifitemlistToFulfill = new ItemFulfillmentItemList();
ifitemlistToFulfill.item = ifitems.ToArray();
newItemFulfill.itemList = ifitemlistToFulfill;

WriteResponse writeRes = _service.add(newItemFulfill);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add and inventory detail subrecord for each line item
2. Then you will have to set the **serialnumber* and **qty**

You cannot add a comma-separated list as you must specify the qty

I am not familiar with the C# api, only the JS and Java api which all have the same workflow (inventory detail subrecord)

Comment: I ended up creating an inventory assignment for each serial number used per order line number and setting the quantity for that serial number on the Inventory Assignment. I also set the quantity of the line item to the total of all serialized items. The serialNumbers field also had to be used by adding all serial numbers in a comma separated list. This works by updating NetSuite as expected.

Answer (score 0):

On the item fulfillment item, there is a text field called serialNumbers. Add them by way of a comma separated list.

Comment: I have tried this, but I still get the same error. There is an "inventoryDetail" field, but this doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for.